# Basic research problems references

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, open-problems, journals

I have been looking for research problems in pure mathematics that I can try to solve for publishing papers. I am quite aware that it takes a lot of time and effort to get to a level where I can do some "serious" research work. Meanwhile, I was thinking that, may be, I can try to solve problems which are at the level of 1st year graduate level (or even Master's level). By "level", I mean that a 1st year grad student should know all the terms used in the paper.

I understand that maintaining a list of unsolved/open problems is an extremely tough task and probably the best method is to look for journals/papers where authors include open/unsolved/extension of the problems.

I would appreciate if you can include here:

(i) List of problems (I have also collected a list of unsolved/open problems from the internet which I would be happy to share here in one of the answers).

(ii) Journals which concerns articles at the "level" mentioned above (For e.g. I hope that this list will exclude annals of math, Inventiones Mathematicae or any top journals which mostly include high level research papers. The American Mathematical Monthly is an excellent source.)

Remarks:

1) I admit that it seems like a very vague question but I am also confident of the fact that many other fellow students are looking for such a source. If the community feels that it should be closed, I will also second it.

2) One of the great sources for finding research problems are conferences (or proceedings of ICM ) where the leading researchers include open problems, but those problems, in my view, seem to be untouchable for most of the 1st year graduate students.

3) From one point view, there is a related question about [letters in mathematics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17094/which-are-the-best-journals-for-letters-in-mathematics-bordering-with-mathemati). This is definitely one of the answer I would have expected for this question.

I will be glad to provide any details if needed. Kindly let me know if I should post this question somewhere else.

Comment: I can hardly imagine how this might work without an advisor to guide you towards meaningful and doable projects; lists of open problems, almost by definition, are problems which experts have thought about and were not able to solve, so these do not seem suitable for someone entering a field.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker On one hand, I do believe that getting in touch with an advisor is a good way, but I also feel we should have some idea about what we want to do. Sometimes, it seems very unprofessional to approach any researcher without anything in your mind. You would be entirely at the mercy of the researcher. While, if you have something to talk about, he/she may be interested in, at least, listening to your proposal. (PS I don't mean only open problems but expositions and other means for publications as well)

Comment: This sounds a little bit like “Where can I find money?”

Comment: It is not only about open/unsolved problems but also about the journals which include papers that grad students can check.

Comment: Dear MUH, Contemporary mathematics is so advanced that there is no way one can do a quality research without years of study and a good advisor who would guide you through the literature. There are open problems with elementary and easy to understand statements, but the reason why they are still open is because they are too difficult. Are you a graduate student? You can reach me for a private conversation by an email. You can find it online.

Answer (score 3):

- G. Eric Moorhouse's [list](http://ericmoorhouse.org/problems.html) of open problems, mainly focusing on finite geometry.
- Douglas B. West's [list](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/openp/) of open problems in Graph theory.
- The [open problem garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Mohammed Ghomi has a beautiful [list](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/Papers/op.pdf) of open problems on curves and surfaces, but perhaps most of them are out of reach.

Comment: Wow! I like this list a lot.